# Emacs can not see mode.el in site-lisp

Tags: init-file, site-lisp

I installed Smalltalk from source which comes with its own mode. The files smalltalk-mode.el and smalltalk-mode.elc are placed in `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/` and this path is in my `load-path` but Emacs can not recognize `.st` files as Smalltalk mode. I also tried `(require 'smalltalk-mode)` in my `init.el`, but didn't help. Why is this happening?

Comment: `smalltalk-mode` is probably just not set up to be the default mode for .st files. Try opening one and then doing `M-x smalltalk-mode` to see if you installed it properly in the first place.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 `M-x smalltalk-mode` activated the mode, i have now colors and Smalltalk activated

Comment: Is there not a commentary section in `smalltalk-mode.el` with installation instructions?  If not, you might raise an issue upstream to have such documentation added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smalltalk-mode` requires configuration to be the default mode for `.st` files. In order to have it there, you need to add this to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.st\\'" . smalltalk-mode))
```